# ArangoDB temperature sensor database

Tags: node.js, express, arangodb

i want to create a small prototype app for temperature sensor visualization.
At first only really static, which means only one Date/Value pair.
The API that I want to write in node.js with express which should connect to ArangoDB.
Is it better to use Foxx or is express okay?

Each Sensor has:

- ID:int
- Name: string

and relate to a set of

- time: Date
- value: int

Key/Value store will be to less because in the feature will a dataset will have battery level and more.

I'm searching for help to start with it.
Is this the right way? https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/examples-and-query-patterns/actors-and-movies-dataset-queries/

Update:

I make this in the Arango Management Interface.
Is better to use a object as root or start with a array?

```
{
  "sensors": [
    [
      {
        "name": "sensor 1",
        "data": [
          {
            "Time": "10.10.10 10:05:05",
            "Value": 30
          },
          {
            "Time": "10.10.10 10:05:05",
            "Value": 30
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "sensor 1",
        "data": [
          {
            "Time": "10.10.10 10:05:05",
            "Value": 30
          },
          {
            "Time": "10.10.10 10:05:05",
            "Value": 30
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```